# How to search all Questions & Answers on specific keyword with PHPstack library?

Tags: support, api, stackapps

I am trying to build a page specific to one keyword which should pull all the questions and their respective answers from Stack overflow. I tried phpstack 1.1.1, but no luck. I saw a

```
function search($opt){
 return $this->request('search'. $opt);
}
```

This function will be useful or not?

Answer (score 1):

You're using my library, PHPStack.

From what I can tell you're attempting to search via tags?

It's a while back since I used it, but if I remember correctly this code should give you a basic example of how to use the search method:

```
<?php

require_once('lib/requestcore.class.php');
require_once('phpstack.class.php');

$so = new PHPStack('stackoverflow.com', 'yourAPIkey');

var_dump($so->search(array(
   'tagged' => 'tags;required' 
)));
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, I am new to Stack overflow API and looking to fetch all Questions and answers to a specific keyword i.e. "PHP" , "how to" etc. I am looking to search different keywords and get the data to display on my app. Just wondering if that is allowed and possible via your API.

Comment: is there a documentation available for your API. I like it but somehow i have less programming experience to figure things out of my own.